# ruby: sort array of symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, symbols

since symbols do not respond to the <=> method used by sort, does anyone have a technique to sorting an array of symbols?  interested in seeing some other ideas.

Comment: You should remember that a Symbol is not a String, but rather a number with a pretty name. I understood your question as how to sort Symbols by `object_id`

Comment: I can't say for certain, but if you're sorting symbols alphabetically, you may be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, `symbols.sort_by {|sym| sym.to_s}` works.

Also in 1.9 symbols *do* respond to `<=>`, so there you can just do `symbols.sort`.

Comment: And on 1.8.7, `symbols.sort_by &:to_s`

Comment: @guns: Using Symbol#to_proc to sort symbols? That's gotta be ironic!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to work on older rubies as though they were 1.9 you can just define <=> on Symbol

```
class Symbol
  include Comparable

  def <=>(other)
    self.to_s <=> other.to_s
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `backports` gem:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'backports/1.9.1/symbol/comparison'
[:a, :d, :c, :b].sort
# => [:a, :b, :c, :d]
```